# Can I increase Xubuntu 16.4 partition size after deleting dual boot partition? Do I need to use live CD?

Tags: partitioning, xubuntu, gparted

I set up a dual boot with Zorin OS9 and Xubuntu 16.4 and have since deleted the partition containing Zorin, so I am only running Xubuntu. (I much prefer Xubuntu, along with its support community.)  I would like to resize my Xubuntu partition now, but in Gparted, it is to the right of the now-unallocated partition I cleared, but I cannot seem to resize Xubuntu and gain memory. Is there any way I can do so without reinstalling the entire Xubuntu OS?  Do I need to use the live CD, and can I do so without a loss of data?

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: Yes to both questions. Note that /dev/sda6 is inside the extended partition /dev/sda2, and you'll have to resize it first. You'll also need to [reinstall grub](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). It's also a good idea to backup all data you don't want to loose.

Answer (score 1):

In order for this to work, you need to boot a LiveCD of Ubuntu. In that case, all your drives will be unmounted, which makes it safer. After you have booted it, open up `gparted`.

Once that has loaded, you will need to right-click on the `/dev/sda2` and click on `Resize/Move`. We need to do this since we have a partition within another partition. The outer partition, which is `/dev/sda2` is the one we'll need to increase first. Increase it to the left. Then click Apply.

This should increase the outer partition. Once that's done(after refreshing), click on the `/dev/sda6` and increase it to the left again.That will increase the inner partition which is in turn, your Xubuntu partition. Click Apply and you should have the space returned to you.

If you want to be extra careful, you can run [boot repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair), to make sure that you boot into Xubuntu, but generally, it should work.